# Stop main thread until WCF Call returns?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I am new to web services and started out with WCF. I have multiple web service calls, each of which are done asynchronously. But my problem is that the main thread should stop until all the web service calls return and when all the web service calls return only then it should proceed.

I tried two things here :

1. used a Boolean variable and an infinite loop to stop the main thread. I change the value in the `Completed` method of the web service call. It resulted in an infinite loop and the `Completed` never got called.
2. I made the web service call from the main thread and after making the web service call, I called the Join method on the main thread to stop this thread until the web service returns.

This is the code snippet :

```
ServerMonitoringBoardDataService.ServerMonitoringBoardDataServiceClient c = new ServerMonitoringBoardDataService.ServerMonitoringBoardDataServiceClient();
c.GetEnvironmentAndServersCompleted += new EventHandler<ServerMonitoringBoardDataService.GetEnvironmentAndServersCompletedEventArgs>(c_GetEnvironmentAndServersCompleted);
c.GetEnvironmentAndServersAsync();

void c_GetEnvironmentAndServersCompleted(object sender, ServerMonitoringBoardDataService.GetEnvironmentAndServersCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var x = e.Result;
}
```

The reason I am facing problems is that,the multiple web service calls returns data as lists and I have done some operations on this data and then displayed it on the UI.The web service calls are made in a static constructor,so as to fetch the data only once and manipulate and display it many time.

But what happens is that the main thread does not stop until the data is fetched and moves onto perform the operations,where I get a Null Exception.

Please suggest a way out for me and also why the above approaches didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help on this.

Comment: I also tried to put the Web service call into a 'Task' and after calling the web service I called the Task.WaitAll() method.But this too didn't work.

Comment: Sorry for this,i'll check all my previous questions here and mark the appropriate answers,but for now please help me with the above question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest to code would be to use the async operation model (i.e. you call `BeginXXX` and it returns an `IAsyncResult` to you) and follow the procedure outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228967.aspx) for all of your async calls. This model is supported out of the box if you used the service proxy generator that comes with Visual Studio.

You will start by making the async calls:

```
var async1 = service.BeginFoo();
var async2 = service.BeginBar();
// more similar calls
```

And then end them one by one -- order does not matter:

```
var result1 = service.EndFoo(async1);
var result2 = service.EndBar(async2);
// etc
```

Of course in practice you will need to add error handling, so it won't be quite as short.

Comment: The calls to the web service return void,so I'll not be able to use this method and also I do not manually end the web service calls.The Completed event gets fired automatically.Also Iam not able to get the IAsyncResult object,so I am not able to use AsyncWaitHandle.

Comment: @Mohnish: You can use this method no matter what the WS returns because `BeginXXX` *always* returns an `IAsyncResult`, you just won't have `var resultX = ` in front of the `EndXXX` calls. Switch from event-based to this pattern, it will make things much easier for you. If you *really* **cannot** do this, tell us why.

Comment: I do not have a BeginXXX method with me.I only have GetXXXAsync() method to start the web service call which returns void and How do i switch from the event-based pattern. i have created my web service using visual studio as a 'WCF Service'.

Comment: @Mohnish: Did you generate the service proxy with VS's "Add Service Reference" function? If so, there is a checkbox that makes it automatically generate `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX` as well.

Comment: Yes i have generated the service proxy using VS's Add Service Reference.I do not find any such checkbox,it only asks me the Web Service URL and has 'Go' ,'Discover' and Namespace options.Also when i open the Advanced settings the Checkbox which says 'Generate asynchronous operations' is disabled and checked.

Comment: I tried to search the net and understood that BeginXXX and EndXXX methods were available earlier but not in .NET 4. I am using .NET 4.Can someone help me on this one.It's really urgent.